# taking ha-jdbc config file out of the war

Tags: java, configuration-files

i have a config file for ha-jdbc. i would like that the users change it according to their wish so it should be outside the .war file. so far i was not successful in doing it. any knowledgable guy out there to help me?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what config file is for, but you can keep out in home directory of user or say `${user.home}/yourApp/yourConfig.conf`  and make your app to read it from here.

You can Obtain platform independent user home hdme dir by

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

Comment: hi jigar, thanks, but i was wondering if these could be done without using java, as the whole action of ha-jdbc generally is not done with java.

Comment: `ha-jdbc` I don;t know it for now